# read specific size of data from boost asio udp socket

Tags: udp, boost-asio

I want to read specific number of bytes from udp socket. In tcp socket I can use            socket.read where I can specify the amount of data to receive. I don't find similar function for UDP socket. I am using receive_from() where I can specify the amount of data to read, but if there is more data then no data is read and I get following error.

```
"A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself"   std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
```

I am not able to find what value do I need to give for message_flags (3rd arg to receive_from) so that it will read the number of bytes specified. Currenly I am using the following code to read data but it either reads all data or no data.

```
        size_t size=socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer((const void*)&discRsp,sizeof(DataStructure)),remote_endpoint,0,errors);
```

Comment: there is no `ip::tcp::socket::read()` method, perhaps you mean the `read()` [free function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/receive/overload1.html)?

Comment: oops my bad. Yes Sam I meant read() free function. But that function doesn't accept UDP socket since its datagram socket. What are my options here :(.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::receive_buffer_size(65536));`